# How to alternate style (background color ) for div different divs?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

How to alternate style (background color with jquery) for div inside div with id="container" alternately ( even and odd ) if I have HTML like this

```
<div id="container">
   <div></div> 
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
...
</div>
```

I know with table like

```
  $('#container>div:odd').css("background-color", "#ff0000");
  $('#container>div:even').css("background-color", "#00ff00");
```

but the all the [divs] should have different colours...?no div should have the same colour ..can any one help me..

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
var colors = ["f00", "0f0", "00f", "ff0", "0ff", "f0f"];

$('#someid .bar').each(function(i) {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#'+colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

For random colors, you can use this:

```
function randomColor() {
    return 'rgb('+
        Math.round(Math.random()*255)+', '+
        Math.round(Math.random()*255)+', '+
        Math.round(Math.random()*255)+')'
}

$('#someid .bar').each(function(i) {
   $(this).css('background-color', randomColor());
});
```

Demo:

> http://jsbin.com/eqoyi4

Comment: This works for me in Firefox.  Did you not try the demo attached?